Buildroot error compiling host-fakeroot on Alpine
Buildroot compilation fails when it's trying to compile host-fakeroot:
(...)
make[3]: Entering directory '/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/build/host-fakeroot-1.36'
/usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.   -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include  -O2 -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include -c -o faked.o faked.c
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.   -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include  -O2 -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include -c -o communicate.lo communicate.c
In file included from faked.c:98:
communicate.h:73:4: warning: #warning Not using stat64 support [-Wcpp]
   73 | #  warning Not using stat64 support
      |    ^~~~~~~
faked.c: In function 'save_database':
faked.c:624:23: warning: format '%llx' expects argument of type 'long long unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
  624 |     fprintf(f,"dev=%llx,ino=%llu,mode=%llo,uid=%llu,gid=%llu,nlink=%llu,rdev=%llu\n",
      |                    ~~~^
      |                       |
      |                       long long unsigned int
      |                    %lx
  625 |             (uint64_t) i->buf.dev,(uint64_t) i->buf.ino,(uint64_t) i->buf.mode,
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |             |
      |             long unsigned int

(...)

libtool: compile:  /usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include -O2 -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include -c libfakeroot.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libfakeroot.o
In file included from libfakeroot.c:65:
communicate.h:73:4: warning: #warning Not using stat64 support [-Wcpp]
   73 | #  warning Not using stat64 support
      |    ^~~~~~~
libtool: link: /usr/bin/gcc -O2 -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/lib -o simple simple.o  -L/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/lib -ldl
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TIME_BITS=64 -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include  -O2 -I/Builds/dev-tests/buildroot/output/host/include -c -o libfakeroot_time64_la-libfakeroot_time64.lo `test -f 'libfakeroot_time64.c' || echo './'`libfakeroot_time64.c
libfakeroot.c: In function 'common_setxattr':
**libfakeroot.c:140:33: error: implicit declaration of function 'SEND_GET_XATTR'; did you mean 'SEND_GET_XATTR64'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]**
  140 | #define INT_SEND_GET_XATTR(a,b) SEND_GET_XATTR(a,b,_STAT_VER)
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libfakeroot.c:1733:3: note: in expansion of macro 'INT_SEND_GET_XATTR'
 1733 |   INT_SEND_GET_XATTR(st, &xattr);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:686: libfakeroot.lo] Error 1

I've tried both the stable buildroot-2024.11 and the latest via git, same issue.
If I build external toolchain first, apply the fakeroot debian patch 'time64-on-32bit-archs' (from https://sources.debian.org/src/fakeroot/1.36-1/debian/patches/time64-on-32bit-archs/), and then compile it - using the externally built toolchain, it then compiles but with issues:
nm shows some doubled symbols:
$ nm .libs/libfakeroot.a|grep -i "send_"
                     U SEND_GET_XATTR
                     U send_get_stat
                     U send_stat
    00000000000002a1 T send_fakem
    000000000000039a T send_get_fakem
    0000000000000c0d T send_get_stat
    0000000000000c9f T send_get_xattr
    0000000000000b8c T send_stat

From what I understand, the root cause is because musl got rid of the '64' suffixes some time ago.
What would be the best way to handle this problem?
Are there some patches other than the one I tried?
